# Attempting to write a Vigenere Cipher java code with user input

Tags: java, encryption, vigenere

I am attempting to, in java, write a program that will encode a string like a vigenere cipher. An example run would be

```
java Encrypt -e lemon < in.txt > out.txt
```

in.txt should read ATTACKATDAWN, and out.txt should read LXFOPVEFRNHR, and if an insufficient # of args are used it should print the usage statement; However, when I run the encryption method on this, it returns "??¡????¡??£?", and if i run the decryption method on THAT, it returns "?? ???? ????", and if I put in less than the required two args, it returns

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>           at Encrypt.main(Encrypt.java:22)

here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Encrypt
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    String msg = scan.nextLine();
    String key = args[1];

    if (args.length < 2)
    {
        System.out.println("Encryption program by ----");
        System.out.println("Usage: java Encrypt [-e, -d] < inputFile > outputFile");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    else if (args[0].equals ("-e"))
    {
        String emsg = encrypt(args[1], msg);
        System.out.println(emsg);
    }
    else if (args[0].equals ("-d"))
    {
        String dmsg = decrypt(args[1], msg);
        System.out.println(dmsg);
    }

}

public static void usage(String[] args)
{
    if (args.length < 2)
    {
        System.out.println("Encryption program by --------");
        System.out.println("Usage: java Encrypt [-e, -d] < inputFile > outputFile");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public static String encrypt(String key, String msg)
{
    String emsg = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++)
    {
        int m = msg.charAt(i); 
        int k = key.charAt(i % key.length());
        int e = (m + (k - 32));
        char s = (char) e;
        if (e > 126)
            e = (e - (127 - 32));
        emsg += s;
    }
return emsg;
}
public static String decrypt(String key, String msg)
{
    String dmsg = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++)
    {
        int m = msg.charAt(i);
        int k = key.charAt(i%key.length());
        int e = (m - (k - 32));
        char s = (char) e;
        if (e > 126) 
            e = (e - (127 - 32));
        dmsg += s;
    }
return dmsg;
}
}
```

I honestly dont know what I am doing wrong; ANY assistance would be very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because you access the second element of the array:

```
String key = args[1];
```

before you've tested the length of `args`. Get rid of this line entirely, since you don't refer to `key` anywhere else in your application. (A good IDE should have told you this already).

---

For your encryption code, I think you'll find this quite challenging unless you limit yourself to only upper-case (or lowercase) letters. Assuming you go for upper-case, then subtracting 65 from the ASCII value will give you a convenient 0-25 value work with with. Then you can use addition, modulo-26 to achieve your goal.

I've fixed up your encryption, now try doing the decryption:

```
public static String encrypt(String key, String msg) {
  String emsg = "";
  final int offset = 'A'; // 65
  for (int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++) {
    int m = msg.charAt(i) - offset;
    int k = key.charAt(i % key.length()) - offset;
    int e = (m + k) % 26;
    char s = (char) (e + offset);
    emsg += s;
  }
  return emsg;
}
```